# How do I call a Method in C#?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to learn how methods work in C# (Also using the XNA Framework).

This is the method I made.

```
     public void Exit()
    {
        if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
        {
            this.Exit();
        }
```

I'm under the impression that it's in the proper format. But I don't know how to actually call it. Or perhaps I'm doing it wrong?

Comment: The problem you're having is not in calling the method.

Comment: I do not mean to be flippant, Slateboard; but I would strongly recommend a basic programming book or course, and I would set aside ideas of learning the XNA framework until you have a solid foundation in C# itself.

Comment: I've been looking at tutorials, but I couldn't make sense of them so I asked here. The missing bracket was just a bad copy/paste job. I looked up methods on the msdn site, and tried it on my own. This is the result basically.

Comment: An excellent place to start with C# is Charles Petzold's ".Net Book Zero" at http://charlespetzold.com/dotnet/index.html.  It's a free eBook that covers the basics of C# and .Net.  Should get you started.

Comment: @Andrew: That's not the intent of .NET Book Zero.  As the cover page says, it teaches how to apply existing C and C++ skills to C#, it does not cover the basics.  And this question is pretty convincing evidence that Slateboard is a new programmer, not someone looking to switch languages.

Comment: @Ben Voigt:  Yeah, fair enough.  I didn't check his other questions before I suggested this.  Looks like a crash course in OOP techniques is in order.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to start somewhere I guess... You seem to have writen a recursive inifinte loop without knowing it!

```
public void Exit()
{
    if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
    {
        this.Exit(); // this is calling your own Exit() method we we are  in at the moment!
    }
}
```

I think what you want is:

```
public void Exit()
{
    if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
    {
        Environment.Exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: And this will call the method, or is this the method itself?

Comment: This is the method itself. Somewhere you have to call Exit() to call the method. Perhaps you should google around for some C# tutorials.

Comment: @Slateboard looking at some of your other questions can I suggest: using StackOverflow (and forums in general) is good when trying to solve a specific problem you are stuck on, but if you are learning it is better, faster and more comprehensive to start with a good book (or tutorial) instead of asking a question to every facet of something you are trying to learn..

Answer (score 2):

Methods are members of a class (or struct) and are called through an instance of the class.  For example:

```
public class Foo {
    public void Bar() 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Running the Bar method");
    }
}
```

You would then have code somewhere like:

```
Foo fooVar = new Foo();
fooVar.Bar();    // call the Bar method
```

Alternatively, you could define a static method which does not require an instance of the class.  For example:

```
public class Foo {
    public static void Bar() 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Running the static Bar method");
    }
}
```

You would then call this in your code like this:

```
Foo.Bar();  // Foo is the name of class, not an object of type Foo
```

Also check out [Charles Petzold's **.Net Book Zero**](http://charlespetzold.com/dotnet/index.html) for a great introduction to C# and .Net.

Comment: This makes sense. How can I apply this to what I'm trying to do specifically?

Comment: It's unclear from your code exactly what you're trying to achieve.  If you want to write a method called Exit, thenit needs to be a member of a class, and then you need to create an instance of that class.  The alternative is a static method, which doesn't require an instance.  I'll add an example of this to my answer.

Comment: In your example, the keyword "this" refers to the current instance of the class of which Exit is a member.  So if Exit is called somewhere in you code while the user has the Esc key pressed, the method will just recursively call itself until the Esc key is released, or the stack fills up - whichever happens first.

Answer (score 1):

Two things stand-out:

1. You're missing a `}` at the end.
2. `this.Exit()` is a recursive call.

Methods are always declared on objects (like classes) and `this` refers to the current object, so `this.Exit()` will continuously call itself while the <kbd>Esc</kbd> is held down.

What is it that you are trying to accomplish with your code?

Comment: I'm basically trying to learn exactly how to use methods. Outside of that, it's not tied to any specific program yet.

Answer (score 0):

For this particular method you just call it like this:

```
Exit();
```

insert that as a line anywhere and it will work. Before you do that though check the `this.Exit();` line, you don't want to be recursively calling yourself....

But looking at the other lines of code in the method i'm not sure that's exactly what you want to do - do you want to exit when a specific key is pressed in conjunction with the `Esc` key?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game` (which you are inheriting from (I think)) provides an 'Update' method which you should override.

Overriding basically replaces method of the base class with whatever you want. In this case calling a method which checks the state of the keyboard and exits when escape is pressed.

Update is called every time the game should, unsurprisingly, update itself (what's on the screen, player position, etc.)

```
protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
       // ....

         ProcessKeyboard(); // Calls into ProcessKeyboard()

       //....
     }

private void ProcessKeyboard () // A new method
{
    if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
    {
         this.Exit(); // Provided from Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
    }

    // Handle other keys down here.
}
```